# Calculating the maximum distance of eddy current from induction cooktop

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I was wondering if anyone knows what the maximum distance an induction coil can induce eddy currents on a ferromagnetic material?

I have an induction cooktop and was curious if I could mathematically calculate the distance eddy currents would still heat a cast iron pot. I don’t have a physics background so was hoping someone could point in me in right direction.

The idea would be that if I understood how the distance is influenced I could change the coil design to change the performance (spacing and number of turns).